# How to determine the highest addressable memory?

Tags: memory-address

"A memory has 1024 storage units with a width of 64. Suppose the memory is byte addressable. What is the address of the highest addressable memory position?"

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

1. byte addressable means individual bytes in a word have their own addresses.
2. there are 8 bytes in a 64 bit word.
3. therefore 8 x 1024 = 8192 addresses overall.
4. highest address therefore 8191.

I believe this to be true but am not a 100% sure. Please indicate where my logic falters if indeed it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say 1023.

There are 1024 storage locations, each numbered 0 to 1023, and each storage location holding 64 bits.

So you have a computer where a byte contains 64 bits. A byte is not 8 bits, but the minimum size of a memory location. All modern computers use 8 bits on a byte, but some older computers used 7, 9 og 14 bits on each byte.

But it's a really badly written question, because it does not define what a storage location is. So your interpretation might be right assuming a standard 8 bit in a byte cpu.

Comment: Byte is **always** 8 bits. The same as kilogram is always 1000 grams.

Comment: @scopchanov - That is not correct.  Read what Wikipedia says about it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte.  In fact, it is incorrect *historically*, and also incorrect in that (unlike kilogram) there is no *international standard* that defines "byte".  When standards want to talk about a (specifically) 8-bit byte, they typically use the term "octet" rather than "byte".

Comment: +1 for @StephenC.


@ scopchanov A byte is NOT always 8 bits. On the other hand, an octet is. In C, CHAR_BIT is the macro that defines the size of a 'char'.